# Connection has not been initialized when using SqlCommand with mini profiler

Tags: c#, sqlcommand, mvc-mini-profiler

I'm receiving the error "Connection property has not been initialized" with the following code:

```
DbConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connStr);
connection.Open();
connection = new StackExchange.Profiling.Data.ProfiledDbConnection(connection, MiniProfiler.Current);
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("GetLanguages", connection as SqlConnection);
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
command.CommandTimeout = 240;
command.ExecuteReader();
```

when it gets to the command.ExecuteReader(); line.

If remove the line

```
connection = new StackExchange.Profiling.Data.ProfiledDbConnection(connection, MiniProfiler.Current);
```

then the code works fine.  What is it about the profiled db connection that is causing my execute reader to throw the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is it about the profiled db connection that is causing my execute reader to throw the error?

Well after creating a `ProfiledDbConnection`, it's no longer a `SqlConnection`, is it? So this line:

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("GetLanguages", connection as SqlConnection);
```

is effectively:

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("GetLanguages", null);
```

... which doesn't bode well for executing the query. This is why using `as` unconditionally is a bad idea - if you'd used a cast expression instead, a more useful exception would have been thrown.

It's not clear to me from the MiniProfiler documentation how you're meant to use a `ProfiledDbConnection` with a `SqlCommand`. You quite possibly want to use [`ProfiledDbCommand`](https://code.google.com/p/mvc-mini-profiler/source/browse/MvcMiniProfiler/Data/ProfiledDbCommand.cs?r=aa60d35493373be23ff4e6fd714a930af368eb43) instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  So a second question if you're kind...  The mini profiler is advertised as working with SqlConnection and I've got a bunch of legacy code I'm trying to profile.  Full of SqlCommands etc.  What is the recommended way to profile this code?

Comment: @GilesRoberts: As I said in the answer, "It's not clear to me from the MiniProfiler documentation how you're meant to use a `ProfiledDbConnection` with a `SqlCommand`." I've never used MiniProfiler myself.